# Using Mechanize To login to gmail

Tags: beautifulsoup, mechanize-python

I am trying to scrap gmail.com and have used mechanize to authenticate but since gmail has two step authentication it was quite tricky but i managed to login but i face loading problem. 
My code is

```
from os import system
import sys
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio
import urllib, urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
import unicodedata
import mechanize
import cookielib
import time


cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
br = mechanize.Browser() 
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.open("https://www.gmail.com")

br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form.set_all_readonly(False)
br.form['Email'] = 'vivek0293@gmail.com'

br.submit()

br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['Passwd'] = '*******'
br.submit()

print"Success"

soup = BeautifulSoup(br.response().read(),"html.parser")

for row in soup.find_all('div'):
    print "hi"
    print row.text
```

My Output looks like this:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7      /Users/vivekrahul/PycharmProjects/untitled/sample.py
Success
hi

hi
Loading vivek0293@gmail.com…Loading standard view |  (for slow connections)This is taking longer than usual. Try reloading the page.If that doesn't work, you can:Disable Labs and try again.If you're on a slow connection, try .For more troubleshooting tips, visit the Help Centre.
hi
Loading vivek0293@gmail.com…
hi
Loading vivek0293@gmail.com…
hi

hi

hi
Loading standard view |  (for slow connections)
hi
This is taking longer than usual. Try reloading the page.If that doesn't work, you can:Disable Labs and try again.If you're on a slow connection, try .For more troubleshooting tips, visit the Help Centre.
hi
If that doesn't work, you can:Disable Labs and try again.If you're on a slow connection, try .For more troubleshooting tips, visit the Help Centre.
hi

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: What are you trying to get essentially? There is Javascript involved so if you are trying to get what you see in your browser that won't be happening with mechanize.

Answer (score 0):

After login submit basic html view form as shown below, you will be redirect to basic HTML view of gmail.

```
  GMAIL_URL = 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/'

  soup = BeautifulSoup(br.response().read(),"html.parser")
  form = soup.find("form")
  action = form.get('action')
  post_url = GMAIL_URL + action
  g_html = self.session.get(post_url)
  gmail_doc = BeautifulSoup(g_html.text, 'html.parser')
```